# Find distinct parent node full path

Tags: xslt

Below Xml has two parent Nodes named "**Pattern**" and "**Members**". Pattern is a flat sub set from Members. Where as Members has treeview structure.

Input Xml:

```
<Root>
    <Pattern name="A">
        <Member id="2" name="Member2" Selection="Yes"/>
        <Member id="3" name="Member3" Selection="Yes"/>
        <Member id="6" name="Member6" Selection="Yes"/>
        <Member id="20" name="Member20" Selection="Yes"/>
    </Pattern>  
    <Members>
        <Member id="1" name="Member1" Selection="Yes">
            <Member id="2" name="Member2" Selection="Yes">
                <Member id="3" name="Member3" Selection="Yes"/>
                <Member id="4" name="Member4" Selection="Yes"/>
            </Member>
            <Member id="5" name="Member5" Selection="Yes">
                <Member id="6" name="Member6" Selection="Yes"/>
                <Member id="7" name="Member7" Selection="Yes"/>
            </Member>
            <Member id="8" name="Member8" Selection="Yes">
                <Member id="9" name="Member9" Selection="Yes"/>
            </Member>
            <Member id="10" name="Member10" Selection="Yes">
                <Member id="11" name="Member11" Selection="Yes"/>
            </Member>
            <Member id="12" name="Member12" Selection="Yes">
                <Member id="13" name="Member13" Selection="Yes"/>
                <Member id="14" name="Member14" Selection="Yes">
                    <Member id="15" name="Member15" Selection="Yes"/>
                    <Member id="16" name="Member16" Selection="Yes">
                        <Member id="17" name="Member17" Selection="Yes">
                            <Member id="18" name="Member18" Selection="Yes"/>
                            <Member id="19" name="Member19" Selection="Yes"/>
                            <Member id="20" name="Member20" Selection="Yes"/>
                        </Member>
                    </Member>
                </Member>
            </Member>
        </Member>
    </Members>
</Root>
```

Can any one help me on getting all parent nodes from **Pattern** based on **Member**s from all ancestors based on attribute **id**

Below is the logical set of Pattern Members fullPath.

```
<!-- Parent Member for Member2 -->
<Member name="Member1"/>

<!-- Parent Members for Member3 -->
<Member name="Member1.Member2"/>
<Member name="Member1"/>

<!-- Parent Members for Member6 -->
<Member name="Member1.Member5"/>
<Member name="Member1"/>

<!-- Parent Members for Member20 -->
<Member name="Member1.Member12.Member14.Member16.Member17"/>
<Member name="Member1.Member12.Member14.Member16"/>
<Member name="Member1.Member12.Member14"/>
<Member name="Member1.Member12"/>
<Member name="Member1"/>
```

the above list has duplicates. so the output required is as below

```
<!-- Unique Parent Members for All levels -->
<Member name="Member1"/>
<Member name="Member1.Member2"/>
<Member name="Member1.Member5"/>
<Member name="Member1.Member12.Member14.Member16.Member17"/>
<Member name="Member1.Member12.Member14.Member16"/>
<Member name="Member1.Member12.Member14"/>
<Member name="Member1.Member12"/>
```

Thanks,

Comment: share your xslt

Comment: I am new to XSLT and I am asking for the answer. Share me your answer.

Comment: Please state if you can use XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="ref" match="Members//Member" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', //Pattern/Member/@id)/ancestor::Member"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Member">
    <Member name="{string-join(ancestor-or-self::Member/@name, '.')}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/94AbWC2

Comment: Thanks Martin. It helped in XSLT2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're limited to a XSLT 1.0 processor, you could use:

***-- simplified thanks to Martin Honnen's suggested approach in his answer --***

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="member-by-id" match="Member[ancestor::Members]" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('member-by-id', Pattern/Member/@id)/ancestor::Member"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Member">
    <Member>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::Member">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </Member>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <Member name="Member1"/>
   <Member name="Member1.Member2"/>
   <Member name="Member1.Member5"/>
   <Member name="Member1.Member12"/>
   <Member name="Member1.Member12.Member14"/>
   <Member name="Member1.Member12.Member14.Member16"/>
   <Member name="Member1.Member12.Member14.Member16.Member17"/>
</output>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael amazing. It helped me a lot.